# Series with an exponential term containing a sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

can anyone help me with the convergence of this series
$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \exp(-c\sum_{j=1}^x j^\beta)$
for $-1<\beta<0$?
Which convergence criterion can be useful here?
Thanks

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think something should be fixed, but this looks the right way.P.S.: yes, $c>0$ whereas $\beta$ could also take value $-1$...

Answer (score 0):

If $c>0$: (courtesy to Did)

See, $x^\beta$ is convex function. So $$\sum\limits_{j=1}^xj^\beta\ge\int_0^xt^\beta\,dt=\frac{x^{1+\beta}}{1+\beta}$$
So, $$\sum_{x=1}^n \exp(-c\sum_{j=1}^x j^\beta)\le\sum_{x=1}^ne^{-c'x^{1+\beta}}=O\left(\sum_{x=1}^nx^{-2-\beta}\right)$$

As, for any $t>0$ we have $\log x=O( \frac{x^t}{t+1})$

Comment: Sorry but this upper bound goes in the wrong direction when $c$ is positive (which is probably the case of interest).

Comment: You REALLY need to reread your post...

Comment: I am really confused! Where did I again make mistake?

Comment: First case: the inequality gives nothing, the appeal to geometric series is useless. Second case: convexity useless, wrong value of the integral... And so on.